# Unable to create site page in document library. How to create in the document library?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to create modren site page in sharepoint online document library. I have added site page content type to list. While creating page, i am getting blank page and creating a page with random name.  Unable to the created page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a test in SharePoint online and i can reproduce your issue.

We are unable to create site page in document library even with the site page content type added.

You need to create site page in site pages library.

Similar issue post for your reference:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/how-to-do-a-custom-modern-page-library/m-p/116981